# Extracting a count from raw splunk data by id

Tags: splunk

I am trying to get a count from transactional information that is retained within raw data in splunk. I have 3-5 transactions that occur.

One has raw data stating: pin match for id 12345678-1234-1234-abcd-12345678abcd  or pin mismatched for id etc.

I'm trying to count the number of times the pin match occurs within the transaction time window of 180sec.

I was trying to do something like:
|eval raw=_raw |search index=transa
|eval pinc= if((raw like "%pin match%"),1,0) |stats count(pinc) as Pincount by ID

The issue I'm having is it is counting cumulatively over whatever time I am looking at those transactions. Is there a way to attach it to the ID that is within the message or have it count every one that occurs within that time window?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming the pin status and ID have not been extracted:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp "pin" "match" OR "mismatched"
| rex field=_raw "pin (?<pin_status>\w+)"
| rex field=_raw "id (?<id>\S+)"
| eval status_time=pin_status+"|"+_time
| stats earliest(status_time) as beginning latest(status_time) as ending by id
| eval beginning=split(beginning,"|"), ending=split(ending,"|")
| eval begining=mvindex(beginning,-1), ending=mvindex(ending,-1)
| table id beginning ending
| sort 0 id
| eval beginning=strftime(beginning,"%c"), ending=strftime(ending,"%c")
```

After extracting the status ("match" or "mismatched") and the id, append the individual event's `_time` to the end of the status - we'll pull that value back out after `stats`ing

Using [`stats`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/stats), find the earliest and latest `status_time` entries (fields just created on the previous line) by `id`, saving them into new fields `beginning` and `ending`

Next, [`split()`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/eval) `beginning` and `ending` on the pipe we added to separate the status from the timestamp into a [multivalue field](https://docs.splunk.com/Splexicon:Multivaluefield)

Then assign the last item from the multivalue field (which we know is the timestamp) into itself (because we know that the earliest entry for a `status_time` should always be "match", and the latest entry for a `status_time` should always be "mismatched")

Lastly, [`table`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/table) the id and time stamps, [sort](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/sort) by id, and format the timestamp into something human readable ([`strftime`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/DateandTimeFunctions#strftime.28X.2CY.29) takes many [arguments](https://strftime.org), `%c` just happens to be quick)